# How to get to Hanover or Wolfsburg from Amsterdam

Tags: budget, public-transport, amsterdam

We are getting to AMSTERDAM, ZEEBURG P&R COACH PARK AT ZUIDERZEEWEG on Wednesday morning (19/08/2015) and need to get to either Hanover or Wolfsburg.

Any tips?

Bus or train and which one is more cost effective?

Comment: If you have no idea where to look, you can check [Rome2Rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/) for a quick overview with all the links to booking sites, bus and train operators, etc.

Answer (score 10):

**1. Train**

You can get train tickets at [DB bahn](http://www.bahn.de/p_en/view/index.shtml). If you buy in advance (say now) you can get saver fares ticket for a price of 39,00 EUR. This is for relatively faster connections: 4h 41min. If time is not an issue and you would not mind traveling 6h 35min and changing the train 4 time,there are options for 22,00 EUR. However later you buy more expencive your ticket will be here. The normal price of the ticket is approximately 75,00 EUR.

**2. Bus**

You can also take one of the following buses:

- Flixbus for around 22,00 EUR and 5h duration
- Eurolines Touring for around 31,00 EUR and 6h 15min duration

Those are also promo prices and might change.

**3. Car**

There is also the option of car pooling. There is one person traveling from Amsterdam to Hanover on the day you want at 18:00. That will take a bit more than 5h of travel and cost you 24,00 EUR. [Here](https://www.blablacar.de/fahrt-amsterdam-hannover-222268596?comuto_cmkt=DE_CARPOOLING_ALL_API) is the add. And in general you can check mitfahrgelegenheit or blablacar websites to see if new posts appear for travelers from Amsterdam to Hanover.

Comment: The OP will apparently reach Amsterdam with a bus, not through the airport.

Comment: Yes, but why even mention Schiphol?And far away from what? Sloterdijk is not that far from either Schiphol or Amsterdam Central…

Comment: Indeed mentioning Schiphol does not make sense so i edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

As elsewhere in Western Europe, both are available, buses tend to be longer and somewhat cheaper. In both cases, there are discounts for advance purchase and the prices change depending on demand so you will have to check yourself to see how big the difference is for this particular trip.

There is in any case a direct train from Amsterdam Central Station to either Hanover or Wolfsburg (it's the same Amsterdam-Berlin train). It's not a high-speed train but perfectly decent. On such short-notice, the cheapest tickets are gone so you should expect to pay €50-70 per person. The full fare (always available) is a bit under €100.

When using the train, you can also save some money by sticking to regional trains (in combination with some special tickets) but that's more complicated (check earlier questions on this site for more).

Comment: Not sure about the bit in the Netherlands, but the entire German route from the border to Wolfsburg has a maximum speed of 200 km/h anyway, so the intercity will only be slower than an ICE due to stopping more often.

Comment: @Jan Not a high-speed service was my point (although technically 200 is enough to qualify in some places), whether it's an ICE is a detail.